# Opening specific folder in Ckfinder 3

Tags: php, ckfinder

I'm having difficulties passing a var to Ckfinder for it to open the folder matching the currently edited page.

The wanted folder has the same name as my database field "gallery" that I can pass in the url this way :

```
$url_edit = 'modifier-' . $_GET['page'] . '-' . $data["id"] . '-' . $data['gallery'] . '';
// RewriteRule ^modifier-(.*)-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ admin.php?modif=$1&id=$2&dir=$3 [L]
```

I think this part of Ckfinder's config.php could be the best spot to pass my var `$_GET['dir']` and point to the specific folder (default : 'photos') :

```
if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    die(var_dump('DEBUG')); // DEBUG
    $galleryDir = '/' . $_GET['dir'];
}

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Photos',
    'directory'         => 'photos' . $galleryDir . '' ,
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);
```

I'm opening Ckfinder as a modal using this code from the official documentation (I didn't alter this as I'm not confortable with Javascript) :

```
var button1 = document.getElementById( 'ckfinder-galerie' );

button1.onclick = function() {
    selectFileWithCKFinder( 'ckfinder-input-1' );
};

function selectFileWithCKFinder( elementId ) {
    CKFinder.modal( {
        chooseFiles: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        onInit: function( finder ) {
            finder.on( 'files:choose', function( evt ) {
                var file = evt.data.files.first();
                var output = document.getElementById( elementId );
                output.value = file.getUrl();
            } );

            finder.on( 'file:choose:resizedImage', function( evt ) {
                var output = document.getElementById( elementId );
                output.value = evt.data.resizedUrl;
            } );
        }
    } );
}
```

**PROBLEM :** `$_GET['dir']` doesn't seem to be passed through the modal, so it currently doesn't create the needed `$galleryDir` var (nor the `die()` function used for debug). Am I doing something wrong here ? I'm also open to other methods if this one isn't as good as I believe.

Thanks for the future help !

Comment: I'm guessing that `CKFinder.modal(...)` probably causes separate HTTP requests, that have no connection at all to the URL which you used to load your main page.

Comment: So the trick could be to pass the var through the Javascript ?

Comment: That could be tricky though, trying to find the right place to intercept. An alternative (although one that won't work well if the user has multiple tabs of this admin panel open), could be to put the value of the GET parameter into the session from the "main" page, and then have the CKFinder config read it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CBroe, it actually helped me. Well, the $_SESSION solution seems to be working in most cases so I'm keeping it. It creates a new problem though (question updated)

Comment: Don't know about that, can only recommend that you check the documentation of possible options, for the version that you are using there. _If_ this exists, then I suppose there must be a second property to specify what the "base directory" is supposed to be - because without that, the user could likely navigate further up the file system, than they were supposed to.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add it under a different property than `resourceTypes` to begin with(?), because https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3/?mobile=/api/CKFinder.Models.ResourceType says that _"[r]epresents the resource type (root folder) model."_

Comment: That's the weird thing. I have a 'baseUrl' specified so I was expecting the 'directory' to act as a focus, not to deactivate the navigation options. I'm sure I'm almost there, I'll keep on testing.

Comment: URLs and the file system, are two different things. `baseUrl` applies when it tries to _create_ HTTP URLs to access files. `baseDir` should be set to specify the directory in the file system, https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Configuration/baseURL_and_baseDir

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the lead given by CBroe I figured out a way to pass the variable. Not 100% efficient but satisfying enough for my needs :

Passing the var in a session **before** loading Ckfinder :

```
if(isset($_GET['dir'])) { 
    $_SESSION['dir'] = $_GET['dir']; 
}
```

Then retrieving it in Ckfinder's config.php to dynamically create the new directory variable :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['dir'])) {
    $galleryDir = '/' . $_SESSION['dir'];
}

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Photos',
    'directory'         => 'photos' . $galleryDir . '' ,
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);
```

It works perfectly : the modal focuses on the wanted folder matching the edited page. Passing a specific directory url disallow the ability to browse the folders though as "directory" var considers itself as the root folder.